# ReactJS: Perform a POST & GET request with a button

Tags: javascript, java, html, reactjs, rest

I am trying to do something like a post and get request with one click. I need to do something like that, because practically speaking, I am trying to implement a "create game lobby" button, that when clicked creates a game on the backend which is written in java and also to get the creator directly routed to this newly created game.
Does anyone know a way how to tackle this?

Greetings

Comment: perform the request (with fetch or axios) on the handler function of the button
<button onClick={() => fetch('api')}>open loby</button>

Comment: @Karim, you can call axios.post to create the game on backend and then after successful create, you can return the creator as a response of the same request. You dont need perform two request for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad but I'd put an example on how it could look:

This is how you can create your button:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}/>
```

This is how you can do a post request when the button is pressed:

```
handleClick (event) {
    axios.post('/myUrl')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't make sense to send both post and get requests for the task you are trying to accomplish here. You will have to wait for the game to be created first, and then reroute the user to the game.
The general way of doing this is to return the game id/link as the response to the post request, and then redirect the user to that link.

```js
    async function handleCreateNewGame() {
        const data = this.state.data;
        const res = await axios.post('api/game/create', {...data});
        if(res.status === 200) {
            const game_id = res.data.id;
            window.location.replace(`/game/${game_id}`); //You might want to use something like history.push() instead
        } else {
            alert('Create ERR');
        }
    }
```